# Filter numpy structured array based on partial match to a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, structured-array

I have a follow up question on one I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742767/filter-numpy-structured-array-based-on-multiple-values).  In that question, I sought to sum values in a numpy structured array based on multiple criteria, including matches in a list.  @ali_m provided a successful answer to that question:

```
criteriaList = ("Zone1", "Zone2")
myArray = np.array([(1, 1, 1, u'Zone3', 9.223),
        (2, 1, 0, u'Zone2', 17.589),
        (3, 1, 1, u'Zone2', 26.95),
        (4, 0, 1, u'Zone1', 19.367),
        (5, 1, 1, u'Zone1', 4.395)],
         dtype=[('ID', '<i4'), ('Flag1', '<i4'), ('Flag2', '<i4'), ('ZoneName', '<U5'),
                ('Value', '<f8')])

result = myArray[(myArray["Flag1"] == 1) & (myArray["Flag2"] == 1) 
    & np.in1d(myArray["ZoneName"], criteriaList)]["Value"].sum()
```

This produces the desired result of 31.345.

Now I am trying to figure out how to modify this if I have underscore delimited values in my array and I want to include the row in my sum if there is a partial match to the critieriaList. In the following numpy structured array, the third row includes underscore delimited values.  In this case, I would like to include the value because "Zone1" is included as part of the "ZoneName" value:

```
myArray = np.array([(1, 1, 1, u'Zone3', 9.223),
        (2, 1, 0, u'Zone2', 17.589),
        (3, 1, 1, u'Zone1_Zone3', 26.95),
        (4, 0, 1, u'Zone1', 19.367),
        (5, 1, 1, u'Zone1', 4.395)],
         dtype=[('ID', '<i4'), ('Flag1', '<i4'), ('Flag2', '<i4'), ('ZoneName', '<U10'),
                ('Value', '<f8')])
```

I have tried splitting out the values in the array:

```
str(myArray["ZoneName"]).split('_')
```

but then can't figure out what do do with these without opening a loop and using if statements.  Any assistance woudl be much appreciated.  thanks.

Here is an example of a way this could be approached using a loop and if statements.  This is not functional as written, but outlines my thought process per hpualij's comment.  (This will also cause problems if there is a "Zone14" since "Zone1" is in "Zone14")

```
values = []
criteriaList = ("Zone1", "Zone2")
for criteria in criteriaList:
    zones = myArray["ZoneName"]
    for zone in zones:
        if criteria in zone:
            print ("criteria=" + criteria)
            print ("zone=" + zone)
            value = myArray[((myArray["Flag1"] == 1) & (myArray["Flag2"] == 1)
                & (myArray["ZoneName"] == zone))]["Value"].sum
            print(value)
result = sum(values)
```

Comment: Show us how you would do this with a loop.  It's easier to suggest improvements to working code.

Comment: @hpaulj: see updated question for an outline of my thought process.  It is still half-baked, but seems like it has potential as a less-elegant alternative

Comment: I'm just wondering why are you using `numpy` to solve these kind of issues ? this can be easily solved using `pandas`

Comment: I am not familiar with pandas.  This is a small section of a larger program which uses numpy, hence I have stuck with it. This is also nested called by an ArcGIS tool which I plan to serve up as a web-accessible Geoprocessing Service in the end.  Using only packages that are included in the native ArcGIS install will make that process easier.  That all said, I'm open to all possibilities!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution to my question, but it is quite slow (the actual array has >200,000 records and there are over 50 "zones")  It sums values from a numpy structured array based on multiple fields, where the "Flag1" field == 1 AND the "Flag2" field == 1 and where there is at least one match in the  "ZoneName" field to a list of names in a criteria list. It will find a match if the "ZoneName" field includes at least one value from the criteria list (e.g. "Zone1_Zone3"), it will not double count if the "ZoneName" field includes multiple values from the criteria list (e.g. "Zone1_Zone2"), and it will not match partial matches to the criteria list (e.g. "Zone14").  Thanks @hpaulj for the help!  I welcome any further comments on ways to improve on this, particularly w/ respect to processing speed.

```
import numpy as np
import re
def main():
    #sum values from the array if "Flag1"==1, "Flag2"==1, and "ZoneName" includes
    #either "Zone1" or "Zone2"
    myArray = np.array([(1, 1, 1, u'Zone3', 9.223),
    (2, 1, 0, u'Zone2', 17.589),
    (3, 1, 1, u'Zone1_Zone2', 26.95),
    (4, 0, 1, u'Zone2', 19.367),
    (5, 1, 1, u'Zone1_Zone3', 4.395),
    (5, 1, 1, u'Zone15', 8.565),
    (5, 1, 1, u'Zone2', 7.125),
    (5, 1, 0, u'Zone1', 6.395)],
     dtype=[('ID', '<i4'), ('Flag1', '<i4'), ('Flag2', '<i4'), ('ZoneName', '<U15'),
            ('Value', '<f8')])

    doneList = []  #empty list to track which zones have been calc'd
    values = [] #empty list to store values from loop
    criteriaList = ("Zone1", "Zone2") 
    zones = myArray["ZoneName"]
    for criteria in criteriaList:
        for zone in zones:
            #only calc if the "ZoneName" value from the array includes the criteria
            #in the current loop and the record has not already been calc'd
            if ((find_word(str(np.char.split(zone,'_')), criteria)) & (zone not in doneList)):
                #the key element from previous question
                value = myArray[((myArray["Flag1"] == 1) & (myArray["Flag2"] == 1))
                    & np.in1d(myArray["ZoneName"], zone)]["Value"].sum()
                values.append(value)
                doneList.append(zone) #Needed to that "Zone1_Zone2" is not double counted
    result = sum(values)
    print result


def find_word(text, search):
   result = re.findall('\\b'+search+'\\b', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
   if len(result)>0:
      return True
   else:
      return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`('ZoneName', '<U10')` needs to be  `('ZoneName', '<U11')` to include the final '3'.

Let's focus on one field; we can reference it with a new variable:

```
In [321]: names=myArray['ZoneName']
In [322]: names
Out[322]: 
array(['Zone3', 'Zone2', 'Zone1_Zone3', 'Zone1', 'Zone1'], 
      dtype='<U11')
```

`np.char` has functions that apply string methods to elements of an array.  Let's try `split`:

```
In [323]: np.char.split(names,'_')
Out[323]: array([['Zone3'], ['Zone2'], ['Zone1', 'Zone3'], ['Zone1'], ['Zone1']], dtype=object)
```

I don't think that helps.  We still have iterate to search the sublists.

```
In [324]: np.char.find(names,'Zone1')
Out[324]: array([-1, -1,  0,  0,  0])
In [325]: np.char.find(names,'Zone3')
Out[325]: array([ 0, -1,  6, -1, -1])
```

This looks better.  We now have a numeric array; '-1' for elements that don't have the string.

Functionally this is the same as

```
In [326]: np.array([astr.find('Zone1') for astr in names])
Out[326]: array([-1, -1,  0,  0,  0])
```

I'm not sure how much of time savings the `char.find` has.  Guess we could test it.  :)

Does that get you past the bottleneck?

---

```
In [328]: %timeit np.array([astr.find('Zone1') for astr in names])
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.2 µs per loop
In [329]: %timeit np.char.find(names,'Zone1')
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.4 µs per loop
```

`np.char.find` is actually slower!  On a (5000,) array, the comprehension method is still faster, though the margin isn't as large.

---

Another option is `view` the field as 2 or more fields:

```
In [352]: nn = names.view([('1st','U5'),('dash','U1'),('2nd','U5')])
In [353]: nn
Out[353]: 
array([('Zone3', '', ''), ('Zone2', '', ''), ('Zone1', '_', 'Zone3'),
       ('Zone1', '', ''), ('Zone1', '', '')], 
      dtype=[('1st', '<U5'), ('dash', '<U1'), ('2nd', '<U5')])
In [354]: nn['1st']=='Zone1'
Out[354]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
In [355]: nn['2nd']=='Zone1'
Out[355]: array([False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
In [356]: (nn['1st']=='Zone1')|(nn['2nd']=='Zone3')
Out[356]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
In [357]: (nn['1st']=='Zone3')|(nn['2nd']=='Zone3')
Out[357]: array([ True, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

This takes advantage of the fact that a string of `11` characters can be viewed as 3 shorter strings.

It is a lot faster than the string operations - if you can tollerate the exact character count

```
In [358]: %%timeit
   .....: nn = M.view([('1st','U5'),('dash','U1'),('2nd','U5')])
   .....: (nn['1st']=='Zone1')|(nn['2nd']=='Zone1')
   .....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 264 µs per loop
```

---

With the more powerful `re.match` - about 1/3 the speed of a `find`.

```
In [368]: %timeit [re.match('Zone1',astr) is not None for astr in M]
100 loops, best of 3: 14.7 ms per loop
In [369]: %timeit np.array([astr.find('Zone1') for astr in M])>-1       
100 loops, best of 3: 5.31 ms per loop
```

Oops, I want `re.search` to match later on in the string as well.

```
In [372]: [re.search('Zone3',astr) for astr in names]
Out[372]: 
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='Zone3'>,
 None,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 11), match='Zone3'>,
 None,
 None]

 In [376]: %timeit [re.search('Zone1',astr) is not None for astr in M]
 100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop
```

Better than `match`, and only 1/2 the speed of `find`.  The pattern needs to be refined to distinguish between `Zone1_` and `Zone14`, but that's easy with `re`.

Comment: This is getting closer, but I think that `np.char.split(names,'_')` is going to be needed to address the potential problem of a "Zone14" .  Using `np.char.find(names,'Zone1')`, "Zone14" gets flagged as a match.

Comment: Since the list comprehension isn't slower, it might be worth playing with `re` pattern matching.  That's more powerful than `split`.  Another thought - join the elements into one big multiline string, and use `re`.

Comment: Using `re` is a good suggestion.  Found a good lead at: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173787/string-exact-match).  Using `np.char.split` in concert with boundary matching using `re`I am able to finds matches that are delimited while avoiding partial matches (e.g. "Zone1" is NOT in "Zone14").